# MSBuild -t:pack ProjectReference

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, project-reference

I have a C# solution that contains two net472 projects: `Foo.csproj`, and `Bar.csproj`.

The projects are in classic format (no SDK version).

The projects use PackageRefernce as package management.

`Foo.csproj` depends on `Bar.csproj`.
`Bar.csproj` isn't a nuget package.

I want to create a nuget package of Foo.

I followed this [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild#add-the-nugetbuildtaskspack-package), and I execute the command `msbuild -t:pack Foo.csproj`, that produces the `Foo.nupkg` file.

The problem is that `Foo.nupkg` contains `Foo.dll`, but it doesn't contain `Bar.dll`.
So, when I try to install via NuGet the package `Foo`, I receive the following error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency 'Bar'.
```

What I'm missing?
I hope I have provided all the necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as explained above.
My goal was to automate Azure Devops nuget package generation of two dependant assemblies and publishing one NuGet package.
One of the steps in the Azure pipeline, actually includes execution of `msbuild` with `-t:pack` arguments.

After reading this thread: [about advanced technics of creating NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects), I've concluded that it's better to have 2 different packages.
So I have ended up with modifiying inital pipeline job with additional 2 steps ("set assembly manifest data" and "Copy files") as on the picture.
One set (of these steps) for A assembly and the other set for B assembly.

At the end result was two published Nuget packeges to the feed, where installation of A package in another project resulted auto installation of dependent B referenced package.

Hope this will help further others.

[image: Azure pipeline agent job steps]